# can an android device plugged into my windows 7 laptop steal my data or plant spyware?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, usb, android

Can an android device (smart phone/tablet) plugged into my laptop's usb3 port (ostensibly for charging) actually steal my data, copy files/passwords from browser/email addresses etc. and or plant a spyware program into my laptop to say keep track of any activity especially sensitive stuff as banking/financial transactions, and so on?  I am embarrassed to say I let someone I don't know very well charge his phone by plugging it into my laptops usb while also my laptop was logged in as administrator and also connected to the internet.  Very stupid, yes, but live and learn!
Thanks for your help

Comment: Cheers Magnetic and Sky, makes me feel a bit less anxious.  No apps or any programs were recommended or offered, in fact I remember my computer giving a fleeting message to the effect "cannot recognize the new usb device" when he plugged it in, though he commented that it was already charging his phone and showed me a battery icon on his screen.  Anyway, thanks for your input and I hope to hear more opinions on this.

Answer (score 1):

Usually it's not possible, because by default it doesn't connect as USB drive and Windows by default doesn't run programs automatically from a drive.

That means **it's not impossible**.

He could enable USB drive mode and trick you to run a malicious program from it. (I mean: he could say something like "hey try this app, it's super fun", or "did you know there is a security update to apply to your PC?", then say "strange, it doesn't start", while the malware has been silently installed)

Or, for someone with lots of resources (time and money), it's theoretically possible to simulate an USB keyboard/mouse and input pre-recorded malicious commands.

Answer (score -1):

**No it's not possible.** Because he's just charging his phone. And It's not connected to your laptop as a Flash memory device. So let your friend charge his phone ;)